# в mobx при каждом добавлении элементов в объект, UI реагирует все медленнее и медленнее

Tags: flutter, dart, mobx

использую mobx,

```
abstract class InstStateStore with Store {
  InstStateStore({@required this.objectModel, @required this.cursor});

  @observable
  ObjectModel objectModel;

  @observable
  Cursor cursor;

  @action
  void onItemTap(int segment, int position, int item) {
    cursor = cursor.copyWith(
      segment: segment,
      position: position,
      item: item,
    );
  }

  @action
  void insert() {
    objectModel.object.segments.add(
        Segment.fromJson(objectModel.object.segments[cursor.segment].toJson()));
    cursor.segment++;
    objectModel = objectModel;
  }
}
```

на экране есть кнопка который добавляет элемент в объект из `InstStateStore`:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          instState.insert();
        },
      ),
      body: Observer(builder: (_) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: instState.objectModel.object.segments.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(
                  "${instState.objectModel.object.segments[index].positions}"),
            );
          },
        );
      }),
    );
  }
```

все идет нормально до тех пор пока элементов `ListView.builder` не становится больше и больше, есть ли альтернативный вариант этому, так как приложение будет работать большим количеством таких элементов?

Comment: А без `MobX`, `ListView.builder` с таким же количеством элементов отрабатывает нормально?

Comment: с помощью `setState` тоже есть задержки, но по плавнее и медленнее

Comment: Возможно у вас еще где-то используется instState? Он вполне мог дергать билд других виджетов, из-за чего и появляются такие просадки.

Comment: Еще один вариант, ваш `ListView.builder` каждый раз билдиться, так как `Observer` стоит над ним...

Comment: а как по-другому можно сделать?

Comment: Можно формировать список вручную без `.builder` и передавать его в `ListView()`

Comment: Так же вот эта строчка тоже сильно тормозит процесс `Segment.fromJson(objectModel.object.segments[cursor.segment].toJson())`, сериализация довольна сложная вещь

Comment: просто без него не копируется предыдущий элемент а дублируется, то есть при изменении одного элемента изменяется и предыдущий

Comment: [Deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50460367/how-to-copy-listt-in-dart-without-old-reference)

Comment: `ListView(children: List.generate(instState.objectModel.object.segments.length,(index) => Observer(...)).toList()` вот так?

Comment: можно так, можно через `.map(...)`